# Node Js Gulp - BrowserSync - Gulp watch PortForwarding on vagrant

Tags: node.js, gulp, browser-sync, gulp-watch

Hello guys im Running an vagrant machine with localhost:8088
my gulp task starting the an default local host on : http://localhost:3000/ how is it possible to reload my vagrant localhost:8088 if changes appears (Just the Browser should i use live-reload?
)

```
    gulp.task('browserSync', function () {
  browserSync.init({
    proxy: '127.0.0.1:3005',
    target: "localhost:8088",
    open: true,
    notify: true
  })
});
```

tryed this but still without success

Answer (score 1):

Try to mention open parameter as external and give the port and address in parameters as below

```
{ "host": "localhost", "open": "external", "port": 8088 }
```

Hope this works

Comment: allready tryed get the exception that port 8088 allready in use and it opens on:    Local: http://localhost:8090
         External: http://172.16.1.49:8090

Comment: @mY777 might be that 8088 port was assigned to some processes

Comment: yep vagrant is running on it : i would like  just refresh the url, i don't need an server to vie my changes cause the vagrant machine is already served them but without reload :(

Comment: @mY777 yes, if the port is assigned to some process then it will show as already in use.Try to assign the port which is free.  So if your problem has got solution then mark it as answer so it is useful for anyone with similar problem

Comment: gulp is loading the localhost with port on it 8090 but still don't reload the localhost:8088